# How to select a resultset of users not belonging to a usergroup

Tags: mysql

I have two tables first is user table

```
id  username 

1   xyz

2   abc
```

and a user group table

```
user_id     group_id

1            2

1            3

1            5

2            2

2            3
```

I want to select a resultset of users which doesn't belongs to group id 5.

Comment: Do you want a single row for each user or repetitive? If single row, then all user-group should appear in result-set or any particular.

Answer (score 2):

First all user ids are in group 5. Then list all users exclude these

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT user_id
  FROM group
  WHERE group_id  = 5
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT user.username FROM user 
JOIN usergroup ON usergroup.user_id = user.id 
WHERE usergroup.group_id != 5
```

Comment: It will bring both the values as user_id 1 belongs to other groups also

Comment: @Ryandecosta What about `DISTINCT`?